# Area of intersection between a sphere and a cylinder.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

I was trying to solve this question and I am pretty sure my result is correct, yet I was given wrong marks for it and the teacher refuses to elaborate. So I come to you:

Calculate the volume of an object created by intersection of a sphere

$$x^2+y^2+z^2\le5$$

and a cylinder

$$x^2+y^2\le3$$

Here is my approach:
I am going to use cylindrical coordinates for this.

I know that the radius will be from $0$ to $\sqrt{3}$. Therefore

$$r \in [0,\sqrt{3}]$$

I also know that $\phi$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$.

$$\phi \in [0,2\pi] $$

And I know that $z$ ranges from the lower part of the sphere to the upper part of the sphere.

$$z \in [-\sqrt{5-x^2-y^2},\sqrt{5-x^2-y^2}]$$

Knowing that $x = r\cos{\phi}$ and $y = r\sin{\phi}$ and jacobian equal to $r$, I set up my integral.

$$ 2\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{5-r^2}} r \,dz\,dr\,d\phi$$

The result was approximately $34.9844$ but I was told this is wrong. I couldn't find any online tools and this is driving me nuts. I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Integrating w.r.t. $z$ first makes this correct. You could have been more precise and not used symmetry (since if you were integrating a nonconstant function symmetry wouldn't be allowed) but that shouldn't be enough deduction for a wrong answer.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you for your answer. I think I should go and talk to the teacher then.